# PyMYSQL - Select Where Value Can Be NULL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm using PyMYSQL to query data from a MySQL database. An example query that I want to use is:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count
FROM example
WHERE item = %s
LIMTI 1
```

which would be run using

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM example WHERE item = %s LIMIT 1"
cur.execute(query,(None))
```

or

```
cur.execute(query,(10))
```

The issue is that item can have a value of NULL which results in

```
WHERE item = NULL
```

Which doesn't work in MySQL. Rather it should read

```
WHERE item IS NULL
```

However the value can be integer also. How can I make PyMySQL adjust the query to handle both situations?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a simple function to catch the `None` situation:

```
def null_for_sql(a):
  return "is NULL" if not a else "= " + str(a)
```

and then call the query like that:

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM example WHERE item %s LIMIT 1"
cur.execute(query,null_for_sql(None))
```

Note there is no "=" after "item" in the query

Edit after comments:

```
def sql_none_safe_generator(query,parameter):
  if parameter: 
    return query.replace(%param, "= " + str(parameter))
  else:
    return query.replace(%param, is NULL)

query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM example WHERE item %param LIMIT 1"
cur.execute(sql_none_safe_generator(query,a))
```

Comment: It's on the right track but wouldn't work as it would create SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM example WHERE item 'is null' LIMIT 1

Comment: if I run `print "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM example WHERE item %s LIMIT 1" % null_for_sql(None)` my output is `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM example WHERE item is NULL LIMIT 1`. If I remember weel, `cur.execute` acts just like `print` with `%s` so the executed query will be without "'" around "is null" -- Using Py2.7 BTW

Comment: @user2694306 is right, the whole point of the vals argument in the  execute(q, vals) function is to bind and escape vals eliminating injection attacks. The driver will escape `is NULL` to "is NULL"  leaving you with invalid SQL.